# How do I pass -1 into MAKEWPARAM and get -1 back with HIWORD?

Tags: mfc

Taking this code:

```
WPARAM eTypes[] = 
{
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Sound, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_PlatformAttendant, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Mike, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Attendant, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_OCLM, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_ConductorCBS, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_ReaderCBS, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Chairman, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Prayer, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Student, -1),
    MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Demonstration, -1)

};

for (int a = 0; a < 11; a++)
{
    WORD l = LOWORD(eTypes[a]);
    WORD h = HIWORD(eTypes[a]);
    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("%d %d"), l, h);
    AfxMessageBox(s);

}
```

The `AssignmentType` values are `long` constants.

The `AfxMessageBox` yields 65535 which I know to be the unsigned value for an integer (I think). But I don't want a value of 65535. I want -1 back (if it is indeed -1). It could also be some other value.

So how do I ass -1 in and get -1 instead of 65535 back?

Comment: `WORD` is an unsigned type. The corresponding signed type is `short`.

Comment: @RaymondChen please consider adding your comment as an answer.